# DBunit Circular depedency in dataset.xml

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, dbunit, spring-test-dbunit

Im trying to create dataset for unit test.

```
<dataset>
    <team id="1" lead_id="1" />
    <player id="1" team_id="1" />
</dataset>
```

Player has reference to Team table and vice versa.
So when I run test (no matter what is created first, team or player), it returns exception, because ForeignKey requirements was not met.

How can I fix it? Maybe disable FK for data import or dataset.xml allows to update fields in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, will need to drop one of those DB constraints.  If there is a feature implementation you find that works, please add it here: https://sourceforge.net/p/dbunit/feature-requests/